# How do I make a line break between divs inside a box?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Here an example:

```
<div id=main>
<div>One</div><br>
<div>Two</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#main{
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-direction: reverse;
```

When I run the code, the two div's go side by side, even though there are line breaks. How do I get the line breaks to work?????

Comment: Since you want these to show one above the other, why are you using `display: -webkit-box`? Use a normal display, and they'll appear as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `br` does not really make a difference there. What you need is not a line-break.

You have to specify `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`. It's default value is `horizontal`, that is why you see this result.

#### Warning

Actually you are using an outdated feature, which was later replaced by [`flex`](http://html5please.com/#flexbox).

*You should not use `display: box`*.

`flex` is currently a W3C Candidate Recommendation, and is stable, so you should use that one instead. [Every current browser has support for it](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

Using `flex` you could do this:

```
#main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Laf2/)

Comment: flex doesn't work in safari. (BTW, I was working all day on this and you helped me so much with your answer.)

Comment: @ENM185 Depends on the version of that Safari. Anyways, Chris Coyier has a nice article on mixing the 2 outdated (`box`, `flexbox`) and the current (`flex`) model and achieving the maximum possible browser support: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/